# Node.JS regenerate SSL socket without closing raw socket

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl

I have to write a Node.js application that must...

1) Make a socket connection to a server, send and receive an initial message exchange.

2) Upgrade the socket to SSL, send a login message and receive a status message over SSL.

3) Tear down the SSL connection without closing the raw socket.

4) exchange a message over the raw socket again.

5) Upgrade the socket again to SSL and continue using SSL for the duration of the processing.

I can't seem to figure out how to tear down the SSL connection leaving the raw socket open and usable for non-SSL traffic then upgrade it again to SSL.

The reason for having to do this is that the server I am connecting to uses the initial non-SSL exchange so the client and server can decide what capabilities they both have and if they can switch to SSL or not.  After the server authenticates my credentials over SSL it then spawns off a new process to handle the rest of the session.  To do that is tears down the SSL layer, passes the raw open socket to the other process, the other process then handshakes with the client that it is running then the connection is again upgraded to SSL.  The SSL context can't seem to be passed between processes but the raw socket can.

Comment: I am not very familiar with sockets on node.js but couldn't you simple just keep the open SSL session and don't use it anymore (don't throw it away as it would be deleted and would close the underlaying connection or send SSL end session data). Use instead the underlaying socket. Unless you send data through the SSL connection it should remain silent SSL has AFAIR no own keep-alive mechanism.

Comment: What "other process" is this? Is this another node process via the `cluster` module? Having to re-negotiate SSL in this way is inefficient.

Comment: No, the server I connect to is written in C.  There is a login manager that I connect to and authenticate with.  Then the login manager spawns another C program handing it my open connection.  The other C program is responsible for talking to my application for the remainder of the session.  So on the Node.JS client side there is just one node program running to talk to connect to the server, login, then talk to the server side application.

Comment: I never thought of just abandoning the first SSL layer object and leaving it there.  I can give that a try.

Comment: Nope, leaving one SSL context as orphaned and trying to start a new SSL context on the same raw socket does not work.